# Render large string in react

Tags: html, reactjs, redux, preact

I would like to render a very large string (7+ million characters) in a React app as gracefully as possible.

Is there a way of doing so that won't cause web browsers to freeze for several seconds while rendering takes place?

```
render() {
  return (
    <pre>{props.bigString}</pre>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's a way. Probably you should think on another way to show the string to the user (like download file)..

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string into multiple chunks, rendering each chunk as the user scrolls.

Comment: Thanks Francis - this was my thought too, but the design and page layout don't permit it.

Comment: @RobertKirby You could still chunk the string, but every 100ms render another chunk, basically giving the browser smaller portioned workloads instead of one large workload.